# How to build an array of ArrayList<Integer> in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, arraylist

I wrote a piece of code like this

```
ArrayList<Integer>[]list=new ArrayList<Integer>[128];
```

But Eclipse says

> Cannot create a generic array of ArrayList

I also tried code like this

```
ArrayList<Integer>[]list=(ArrayList<Integer>[])new Object[128];
```

But Eclipse throws exception:

> [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.util.ArrayList;

So how can I build an array of ArrayList< Integer > ?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

`List<Integer> inp = new ArrayList<Integer>(10)` to create list of integers whose size is 10.

Comment: No, its size is 0. Its *capacity* is 10.

Comment: yes, my bad. capacity is 10 and size is 0. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this to create an ArrayList (remember, ArrayLists always have a *theoretically* indefinite capacity, since you can always `add` more elements to them - see [a tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm)):

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

or this to make an array of ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] lists = new ArrayList[128];
```

You will of course have to initialize your ArrayLists:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lists.length; i++)
    lists[i] = new ArrayList<>();
```

Alternatively, you can create an ArrayList of ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> lists2 = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
     lists2.add(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: No, its size is 0. Its *capacity* is 128.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ah, yes. I got it mixed up with the behavior of vectors from C++. What do you think of my edit?

Comment: I simply wouldn't have mentioned capacity, especially as you don't say why it is probably irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your method works!! @Nulano

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you are trying to create an `ArrayList` and an `Array` in the same step, which is impossible.

An `Arraylist` differs from arrays as it is a generic class, which means it has a lot more functionality.

For example:

In your code you are trying to specify a limit to the `ArrayList`, `ArrayList`s don't have a limit, they are expandable.

You can use the `.add()` function to add objects to `ArrayList`s, and get values using the `.get(int index)` function.

Example code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //initialized a new arrayList
myArray.add(7); //added element 7 at index 0
myArray.add(12); // added element 12 at index 1
print(myArray.get(1)) //output 12
```

You can check the documentations for the `ArrayList` class [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really clear,
but to build an array list,this code should be sufficient

```
   ArrayList<Integer> list;
   list = new ArrayList<Integer>(128);
```